# Kotlin - How can I receive an intent from a notification pending intent on an app that is in the background?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-intent

I have a set of notifications for a calling application that I want to trigger a specific intent once it is interacted with (i.e when 'Accept' is clicked, it opens the in-call fragment screen, or if a voicemail notification is clicked, that fragment is opened)

The problem I'm having with this is that, if the application is not in the foreground, these interactions will instead just launch the application to MainActivity without completing the intent.

From what I can tell by debugging, I can trigger `onNewIntent` in MainActivity, but `setIntent(intent)` appears to contain this intent data

`Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x14400000 pkg=com.round2pos.phone cmp=com.round2pos.phone/.MainActivity (has extras) }`

Which is the primary launcher action from the `intent-filter` of the MainActivity in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I've looked at a number of questions on this as well as the Android Docs and none of it appears to be helping me, including:

- Add `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` to the PendingIntent
- Include `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in the resultIntent
- Change `android:launchMode` to `singleTask` or `singleTop`
- Set `setFullscreenIntent` with a High Priority on the notification

None of these have been successful in allowing me to move the interaction to the proper fragment, I'd appreciate some help or guidance in the right direction.

Here's my `NotificationService.kt` where I create the notification and send the intent

```
  val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            channel.description = "Phone Notifications"
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.setShowBadge(true)
            channel.canShowBadge()
            channel.shouldVibrate()

            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            val tapResultIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
            tapResultIntent.action = intent?.action
            tapResultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

            val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(applicationContext)
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity::class.java)
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(tapResultIntent)

            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                applicationContext,
                NOTIFICATION_ID,
                tapResultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            val notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(applicationContext, CHANNEL_ID!!)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
//                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setSmallIcon(notificationIcon!!)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MISSED_CALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setColor(Color.rgb(214, 10, 37))
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
```

And my `MainActivity.kt` where I accept the intent

```
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        setIntent(intent)

        when (intent.action) {
            ACTION_MISSED_CALL -> {
                handleNewNotification(intent)
            }
            ACTION_NEW_VOICEMAIL -> {
                handleNewNotification(intent)
            }
            else -> {
                handleIncomingCallIntent(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    private fun handleNewNotification(intent: Intent) {
        setUpNavigationBar()
        when (intent.action) {
            ACTION_MISSED_CALL -> {
                val historyFragment = HistoryFragment()
                navController.navigate(R.id.historyFragment)
            }
            ACTION_NEW_VOICEMAIL -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.voicemailFragment)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleIncomingCallIntent(intent: Intent?) {
            val action = intent?.action
            activeCallInvite = intent?.getParcelableExtra(INCOMING_CALL_INVITE)
            callerID = intent?.getStringExtra(CALLER_ID)
            callerIDNumber = intent?.getStringExtra(CALLER_ID_NUMBER).toString()

            activeCallNotificationId = intent!!.getIntExtra(INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0)

            when (action) {
                ACTION_INCOMING_CALL -> handleIncomingCall(activeCallInvite, activeCallNotificationId)
                ACTION_INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION -> Log.d(TAG, "INCOMING CALL ${activeCallInvite?.callerInfo}")
                ACTION_CANCEL_CALL -> endForeground()
                ACTION_FCM_TOKEN -> registerForCallInvites()
                ACTION_ACCEPT -> answer()
                else -> {
                }
            }
    }
```